# Prolog rule binding

Tags: prolog

Hi i'm new to Prolog and I think i'm having trouble with the binding of variables.
The question that im working off is [this](http://jsbin.com/qofewozuzi/1/edit?output).

and this is what I have come up with so far:

```
:- dynamic lecture/1.

%teacherNames(['Paul'],[['Bsc4'],['Bsc1']], [['AI'],['Games Design']]).
teacherNames(['Paul'],['Bsc4'],['AI']).
teacherNames(['Paul'],['Bsc1'],['Games_dev']).

group(['Hsoftware'],['Bsc4'],['15']).
group(['total'],['Bsc1'],['127']).
group(['games'],['Bsc1'],['52']).
group(['software'],['Bsc1'],['35']).
group(['web'],['Bsc1'],['15']).
group(['systems'],['Bsc1'],['25']).

room(['B1041'],['32']).
room(['B2008'],['32']).
room(['A0006'],['140']).

student(['Bill Bloggs'],['s00000123'],['Bsc4']).
student(['Andera Martin'],['s00000100'],['software']).

assignRoom:-
    %retract(lecture(TeachersName,TeachersGroup,TeachSubject)),

write('teachers name?'),nl,
read(TeachersName),
%teacherNames(TeachersName),nl,
write('Group for class'),nl,
read(TeachersGroup),

%write('Subject?'),nl,
%read(TeachSubject),
teacherNames(TeachersName,TeachersGroup,TeachSubject),

%GroupName == TeachersGroup,
%group(GroupName,_,_),

    write('Choose Stream'),nl,
read(Stream),

write('time period for class'),nl,
read(Period),

group(Stream,_,_),

write('choose room'),nl,
read(Room),
room(Room,_),
    %%assertz(lecture(GroupName,Subject)).
    asserta(lecture(TeachersName,TeachersGroup,TeachSubject,Period,Room)).
```

my problem is that I want it that 'Paul' will only be able to teach AI to 'Bsc4' and only able to teach 'Games_dev' to 'Bsc1'.
So in this case if I were to input:

```
assignRoom.
Paul %teachers name
Bsc4 %the group that will be going to the class
Hsoftware %the stream name
1 %the time the class will be on
B1041 %the room the class will be held in
```

That works but if i try to put in anything other than those values it fails.
How I want it to work is that if the Group is 'Bsc4' than only Hsoftware will be true and if Group name was 'Bsc1' Hsoftware would be false while software,web etc. will be true and the appropriate values will be bound to lecture.

Edit:

I changed around somethings and what i got is working alot better if i don't take user error into account (which will do for this example).
the new code is in [this link](http://jsbin.com/lajogefuta/1/edit?html) the problem i'm having now is the binding of the Room variable..

if i input

```
 assignRoom.
 Paul.
 Bsc1.
 web.
 1.
 A0006.
```

I get the results I want apart from the RoomNumber always outputs as

```
 lecture(X,C,V,B,N,Y).
 Paul %correct
 Bsc1 %correct
 web %correct
 games_dev %correct
 1 %correct
 B1041 %Should be A0006
```

So what i'm asking now would be how do I fix the binding for the room number.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a list construct for all of your data components? *E.g.*, why is it `room(['B1041'],['32']).` and not `room('B1041', 32)`? Anything that is a single value doesn't need to be a list. You only need a list of you require the flexibility of allowing zero, one, or more elements.

Comment: honestly I didn't even know there was a difference I just thought that is what the syntax was.

Comment: It's fundamental Prolog syntax. You might want to review some introductory Prolog tutorial or get a good introductory Prolog book before tackling this program.

Comment: unfortunately i'm really short on time and finding all this Prolog stuff very confusing lol

Comment: What are the criteria to select the room? In the current form, only the first fact room will be unified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that the room should be explicitly selected, so my suggestion is to show the user what their options are.
First, create a predicate that will print all rooms:

```
print_rooms:- room(N, C), 
              write(N), write(' - '),write(C), write(', '),
              fail.
print_rooms.
```

Second, use this predicate before ask the user to select the room:

```
...
write('choose room: '), print_rooms ,nl,
read(Room),
room(Room,_),
...
```

You can do this much better and cleaner, but this may work. Other thing you must do is keeping asking the user for the room, until he/she select a valid option.

Comment: I added that [link here](http://jsbin.com/homewozito/1/edit?html) but the binding is still off.

Comment: That's because you are entering the classroom name as a variable. When the program ask for the classroom, try using quotes for the input, like 'A0006'

Comment: Otherwise you can remove the quotes on facts room, and change the initial letter on the room to lowercase, like this room(a0006, 140).